# Difference between WebDriver and HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit

i have a little doubt about htmlUnit driver.Do v need to install any web browsers while performing htmlUnit testing?

Answer (score 1):

No. HtmlUnit **is** a web browser. The difference with traditional browser is that it doesn't have a GUI (it's a *headless* web browser), and is driven by your Java code instead of your mouse clicks.

Comment: Should also mention that you can emulate different browsers, in case the OP is looking for that. If possible, I usually emulate for a production system, if not, Firefox. Either way, just a recommendation.